# Why is gulp-rsync not deploying?

Tags: deployment, gulp, rsync

Im trying to deploy to a staging site with gulp-rsync. I'm not receiving any errors but it's not deploying to My server. I would also expect to be asked for the password, which is not happening.

```
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    stylish = require('jshint-stylish'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    bower = require('gulp-bower'),
    sftp = require('gulp-sftp'),
    rsync = require('gulp-rsync');

    gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  gulp.src('build/test_for_rsync')
    .pipe(rsync({
      root: 'build',
      hostname: '*****.wpengine.com',
      username: '*****',
      port: 2222,
      destination: '/wp-content/themes/',
      incremental: true,
      progress: true,
      relative: true,
      exclude: ['/node_modules', '/bower_components'],
      recursive: true


    }));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `return` keyword before `gulp.src`:

```
gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  return gulp.src('build/test_for_rsync')
  .pipe(rsync({
     root: 'build', ...
```

Comment: Ah… the documentation on [npm: gulp-rsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rsync) is old. The README.md on github was [updated](https://github.com/jerrysu/gulp-rsync/commit/bcfd42c7a6fafc29db8501516fc27f2f0940c5e1), but the update isn't shown on npmjs.com.